# How do you call the VSCode extension that shows you the git branch like this

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do you call the VSCode extension that shows you the git branch like this

[image]

Comment: execute a shell command that queries the git branch

Comment: I guess this not exactly VSC extension, but a custom terminal clinet (shell) used as as integrated terminal in VSC. If you are using this terminal outside VSC, you should be able to set VSC up the way it will be used inside.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a [guessing game question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/29/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) (virtually no textual description- only an image)- not to mention that it's based on a wrong assumption that this behaviour is from an extension and not from customizing whatever shell this is' prompt environment variable.

Comment: This is not a VS Code extension and is using the inbuilt terminal. The terminal could be running any command line: Windows Command Prompt, PowerShell, PowerShell Core, Bash, Sh, whatever Macs use!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add to the shell you use a great extension,

- [Oh My Posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/)

and then you might customize VS Code Terminal accordingly.

I wrote about [how to customize Oh My Posh on macOS](https://halfblood.pro/powershell-on-macos/), so you can use that as an example.

It’s official documentation contains instructions for other shells like bash or zsh.

Comment: You only need Oh My Posh as it can be used for all shells ;-)